# How to correctly send data via ajax to telegram via php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, telegram

I made a questionnaire for the site on JS. JS works well, but it doesn't work correctly to send data via ajax to telegram. When sending, it hits error 400. If you set all the variables "hard" and not with a post like $the =question 6:; then everything is normal. It turns out I'm transmitting the data incorrectly. Tell me how to do it correctly.
Js works out as expected before sending it. Everything on the POST goes out(although it writes that everything was sent successfully)

```
function compileForm() {
    // take answers

    var answerInput1 = $('.qwestion-1:checked'),
        answerInput2 = $('.qwestion-2:checked'),
        answerInput3 = $('.qwestion-3:checked'),
        answerInput4 = $('.qwestion-4:checked'),
        answerInput5 = $('.qwestion-5:checked');
    answerInput3Custom = $('#qwestion-3-custom');

    scoreSum = answerInput1.data('cost') + answerInput2.data('cost') + answerInput3.data('cost') + answerInput4.data('cost') + answerInput5.data('cost');

    var answer1 = answerInput1.val(),
        answer2 = answerInput2.val(),
        answer3 = answerInput3.val(),
        answer4 = answerInput4.val(),
        answer5 = answerInput5.val();

    if (answerInput3.hasClass('qwestion-3-custom-choose')) {
        console.log('another');
        answer3 += ' - ' + answerInput3Custom.val();
    }

    // put unswers to inputs
    var sendInp1 = $('#answer-1').val(answer1),
        sendInp2 = $('#answer-2').val(answer2),
        sendInp3 = $('#answer-3').val(answer3),
        sendInp4 = $('#answer-4').val(answer4),
        sendInp5 = $('#answer-5').val(answer5);
    sendInp6 = $('#answer-6').val(scoreSum);

};
$('#final-qwestion__btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var answers = [];
    $('.qwestion').each(function(index, el) {
        var number = index + 1;
        if (index > 4) {
            answers.push(number + ') Номер телефона —— ' + $(this).find('#qwestion__tel-input').val() + '')
      answers.push(number + ') Город : —— ' + $(this).find('#qwestion__gorod-input').val() + '')
        } else if (index == 2) {
            if ($(this).find('input:checked').hasClass('other')) {
                answers.push(number + ') ' + $(this).find('.qwestion__heading').text() + ' —— ' + $(this).find('#qwestion-3-custom').val() + '')
            } else {
                answers.push(number + ') ' + $(this).find('.qwestion__heading').text() + ' —— ' + $(this).find('input:checked').val() + '')

            }
        } else {
            answers.push(number + ') ' + $(this).find('.qwestion__heading').text() + ' —— ' + $(this).find('input:checked').val() + '')
        }

    });
    if (!$('#qwestion__tel-input').val()) {
        $('#qwestion__tel-input').css('box-shadow', '0 0 20px 0px #990033');
    } else {
        $('#qwestion__tel-input').css('box-shadow', 'none');
        answers = answers.join('\n')
        console.log(answers);
        $.ajax({
                url: 'send/send.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    postData: answers
                },
                success: function(resultData){
      alert("Save Complete");
  }
            })
    }
    

});
```

});

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-1'])) {
          $qwestionq = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-1']);
          $qwestionqFieldset = "<b>qwestion1:</b> ";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-3'])) {
          $qwestiona = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-3']);
          $qwestionaFieldset = "<b>qwestion2:</b>";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-4'])) {
          $qwestioz = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-4']);
          $qwestionzFieldset = "<b>qwestion3:</b> ";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-5'])) {
         $qwestionw = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-5']);
          $qwestionwFieldset = "<b>qwestion4:</b> ";
        }
    if (isset($_POST['qwestion-6'])) {
          $qwestions = strip_tags($_POST['qwestion-6']);
          $qwestionsFieldset = "<b>qwestion5:</b> ";
        }    
    if (isset($_POST['gorod'])) {
          $gorod = strip_tags($_POST['gorod']);
          $gorodFieldset = "<b>qwestion6:</b> ";
        } 
    if (isset($_POST['tel2'])) {
          $tel = strip_tags($_POST['tel2']);
          $telFieldset = "<b>qwestion7:</b> ";
        }     
    
    $token = "";
    
        $chat_id_scr = "";
    $txt = rawurlencode($txt);
    $arr = array(
      $qwestionqFieldset => $qwestionq,
      $qwestionaFieldset => $qwestiona,
      $qwestionzFieldset => $qwestionz,
      $qwestionwFieldset => $qwestionw,
      $qwestionwFieldset => $qwestions,
      $gorodFieldset => $gorod,
      $telFieldset => $tel,
    );
    
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
      $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b>".$value."%0A";
    };
    
    $sendToTelegram = fopen("https://api.telegram.org/bot{$token}/sendMessage?chat_id={$chat_id_scr}&parse_mode=html&text={$txt}","r");
```